# Ubuntu Server with GUI - Remote Connection

Tags: linux, user-interface, ubuntu, server, remote-access

I have an Ubunutu 14.04 LTS Server (64-bit) installed on a Cloud Server. As of right now it is a fresh install with no GUI, simply the console.

I want to know if it is possible to set up this server with a minified Unity desktop environment which I can then remote connect into from another computer. I understand the added security risk and etc with installing a GUI on a server.

Any guidance or help would be appreciated

I have searched the web and only found a few forums going over the XFCE environment. Even those were a little unclear. I am not necessarily against the XFCE environment as long as I can install it correctly. So any help there as well would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/.